# limiting the Index size of specific DB column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Good Day,

I have concern about indexing in mysql. I am trying to limit the Index size of specific DB table column which column names like  ###ID.

this seems that the ID looks unique in first 8 bytes instead of entire length.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-on-mysql

Answer (score 2):

As mysql documentation on [creating indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) describes:

> For string columns, indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an index prefix length.
>
> - Prefixes can be specified for CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, and VARBINARY column indexes.
> - Prefixes must be specified for BLOB and TEXT column indexes.
> - Prefix limits are measured in bytes, whereas the prefix length in CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, and CREATE INDEX statements is interpreted
>     as number of characters for nonbinary string types (CHAR, VARCHAR,
>     TEXT) and number of bytes for binary string types (BINARY, VARBINARY,
>     BLOB). Take this into account when specifying a prefix length for a
>     nonbinary string column that uses a multibyte character set.
> - For spatial columns, prefix values cannot be given, as described later in this section.
>
> The statement shown here creates an index using the first 10
>   characters of the name column (assuming that name has a nonbinary
>   string type):
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
> ```

Comment: Thanks sir, this documentation helps me a lot.

Comment: If my answer helped to resolve the issue, then pls mark it as accepted, so other viewers of this topic will know that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size after the field name. You must remove the old key first

```
ALTER TABLE mytab
ADD  KEY `parent` (`parent`(8)) ;
```

Comment: Good day Bernd, what I am trying to do is to limit only the index size. lets say `parent` column is now a key, I want that only the first 8 bytes of a character will be an index. is this posible by doing KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=12?